# Spring Boot 2.7 not connection to IBM MQ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ibm-mq

I have a running spring boot application which should receive Messages from IBM MQ Server. The application is able to start, but the message on the Queue is not fetched.

That's my MqConfiguration Class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class MqConfiguration {

    @Bean()
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MqProperties properties) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setConcurrency(properties.getConcurrency());
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        factory.setReceiveTimeout(properties.getReceiveTimeout());
        factory.setMaxMessagesPerTask(properties.getMaxMessagesPerTask());

        return factory;
    }
}
```

Here is my MqConnectionConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class MqConnectionConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(MqProperties properties, EksconnectUtf8ConverterEventLogger logger) throws ConfigurationException {
        MQConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory = null;
        try {
            mqConnectionFactory = new MQConnectionFactory();
            mqConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(JmsConstants.PASSWORD, "myPass");
            mqConnectionFactory.setStringProperty(JmsConstants.USERID, "myUser");
            mqConnectionFactory.setBooleanProperty(JmsConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
            mqConnectionFactory.setHostName(10.0.0.1);
            mqConnectionFactory.setPort(1414);
            mqConnectionFactory.setQueueManager("*QMGR");
            mqConnectionFactory.setChannel("CL.5.S");
            mqConnectionFactory.setSSLCipherSuite("TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256");
            mqConnectionFactory.setTransportType(CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            mqConnectionFactory.setAppName("myApp");
            mqConnectionFactory.setShareConvAllowed(1);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new ConfigurationException(e.getMessage());
        }
        return mqConnectionFactory;
    }
}
```

And here is a small implementation of my MqGateway is JmsListener:

```
@Named
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = {HandlerErrors.RequestReplyException.class})
public class MqGateway {

    @JmsListener(destination = "QM.TEST.IN", containerFactory = "defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void onMessage(TextMessage message, Session session) throws HandlerErrors.OneWayException, JMSException {
        System.out.println("Message received");
    }

}
```

The Application is able to start without any errors. And I can find any log messages related to MQ. There are messages on the Queue, but the JmsListener Method is not invoked and the Message is not printed to console.

How can I check if connection is working? Why is JmsListener not invoked? Can I get any Information to the log if the connection could have been established? Or where can I start debugging?

Comment: Try adding additional logging into `MqConnectionConfiguration` to check whether a connection is being attempted.